# ¿Como hacer una operación aritmetica entre dos resultados de ajax de manera prolija?

Tags: jquery

Quiero hacer **dos** consultas Ajax y luego una operación aritmética. El resultado de la operación aritmética se inserta en la base de datos mediante otra conexión Ajax. Por cuestiones de prolijidad y además, para poder reutilizar código quiero evitar anidar los Ajax.

`$.ajax({success: function(respuesta1){ return respuesta1;}});`

`$.ajax({success: function(respuesta2){ return respuesta2;}});`

resultado = respuesta1 - respuesta2

`$.ajax({`inserta resultado`});`

Si lograra guardar respuesta1 y respuesta2 en variables que pudiera llamar por fuera del Ajax sería sencillo, sabemos que el valor que le demos a una variable dentro de la función Ajax queda indefinida por fuera del Ajax. Para lograr eso se que debo utilizar callbacks. Así y todo, con el uso de callbacks no puedo llegar a una solución prolija. Entonces, ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: El problema es que estás pensando de manera síncrona mientras tratas con código asíncrono. Las callbacks se ejecutarán cuando se ejecuten, si tú intentas hacer lo que dices, lo que vas a lograr es insertar un valor nulo en la base de datos. El código asíncrono requiere soluciones asíncronas!

Comment: Claro, gracias por responder!. Y cuál seria entonces la solución asincrona?

Comment: Tal vez añadiendo un bloque try, catch y await a las dos llamadas ajax, sirva.
Con el await, el código va a esperar la devolución de los dos llamados ajax, antes de hacer la operación aritmética, ahí ya va a tener los datos de ambas llamadas guardados en las variables mencionadas.